# IF Statement inside array php

Tags: php, arrays

Hi guys i have a code for update my database

```
$users = Sdba::table('tabusuarios');
$users->where('User_Id =', $User_Id);
$data = array('User_Name'=> $User_Name, 'User_Email'=> $User_Email, 'User_Status'=> $User_Status, 'User_Perm'=> $User_Perm);
$users->update($data);
```

My problem is i want to also update 1 more column if this exists something like this

```
if ($_POST["User_Password"]) $data = array('User_Password'=> saltSenha($_POST["User_Password"]));
```

So i want to make a all this togheter

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Why not just say `if (!empty($_POST...)) { $data['User_Password'] = ...; }` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make use of the **`isset`** construct and do like this

```
$users = Sdba::table('tabusuarios');
$users->where('User_Id =', $User_Id);
$data = array('User_Name'=> $User_Name, 'User_Email'=> $User_Email, 'User_Status'=> $User_Status, 'User_Perm'=> $User_Perm);

if(isset($_POST["User_Password"]) && !empty($_POST["User_Password"]))
{
    $data['User_Password']=saltSenha($_POST["User_Password"]);
}

$users->update($data);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$users = Sdba::table('tabusuarios');
$users->where('User_Id =', $User_Id);
if ($_POST["User_Password"]) {
    $data = array('User_Name'=> $User_Name, 'User_Email'=> $User_Email, 'User_Status'=> $User_Status, 'User_Perm'=> $User_Perm, 'User_Password'=> saltSenha($_POST["User_Password"]));
}else{
    $data = array('User_Name'=> $User_Name, 'User_Email'=> $User_Email, 'User_Status'=> $User_Status, 'User_Perm'=> $User_Perm);
}
$users->update($data);
```

Comment: Repetition sucks.  :P

Comment: well said. scope for improvement is always there. the motto is to make a novice understand how to do it :)

Answer (score 0):

Just do this:

```
$users = Sdba::table('tabusuarios');
$users->where('User_Id =', $User_Id);
$data = array('User_Name'=> $User_Name, 'User_Email'=> $User_Email, 'User_Status'=> 

if ($_POST["User_Password"]){
    $data['User_Password'] = saltSenha($_POST["User_Password"]);
}

$User_Status, 'User_Perm'=> $User_Perm);
$users->update($data);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just set the base `$data` array and then if `$_POST["User_Password"]` exists & is not empty, just add that to the array?  Example based on your code below. I find that using a double checking mechanism of `array_key_exists()` coupled with a `!empty(trim())` is the best way to ensure that you are not dealing with junk data or whitespaces in a passed variable like `$_POST`, `$_REQUEST` or `$_GET`:

```
$users = Sdba::table('tabusuarios');
$users->where('User_Id =', $User_Id);
$data = array('User_Name'=> $User_Name, 'User_Email'=> $User_Email, 'User_Status'=> $User_Status, 'User_Perm'=> $User_Perm);
if (array_key_exists("User_Password", $_POST) && !empty(trim($_POST["User_Password"])) {
  $data['User_Password'] = saltSenha($_POST["User_Password"]);
}
$users->update($data);
```